# Where does sandbox payments listed?

Tags: square-connect

`$result = $transactions_api->charge($location->getId(), $request_body);`

`$result` has been successfully charged using sandbox, where can i find them through dashboard?

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox transactions are not visible in your Square Dashboard. The way to view sandbox transactions is to call the [ListTransactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions) endpoint with your sandbox credentials to get a sandbox transaction report. Only live transactions will be visible on your Square Dashboard.

Feel free to visit our Developer Doc for more information on [Testing with the API Sandbox](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox).

Comment: Thank you kaled.. that's all i want to know.. :) i have read the docs but i think i missed that part telling sandbox is not visible on dashboard.. :)