# Where can I see a successful Sandbox transaction?

Tags: square-connect

I can make a successful payment using the square payment form example, and getting the payment-processing page with a reply of the transaction details using the Transacrion API.
Once this completed Can I see this anywhere on my square account? Like a list of successful transaction in the sandbox?

Comment: Hi Tibby, please see this question and let me know if it doesn't help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444572/where-does-sandbox-payments-listed/49452951#49452951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandbox transactions are not visible in your Square Dashboard. The way to view sandbox transactions is to call the ListTransactions endpoint with your sandbox credentials to get a sandbox transaction report. Only live transactions will be visible on your Square Dashboard.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a way to view the sandbox transactions before you go live. Go to this link https://developer.squareup.com/apps and there at the bottom you can see the list of sandbox test accounts. Click open button to view the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox Transactions will not show up on the dashboard.
The only way to see them is to go to the sandbox test page and use the sandbox ID and sandbox location to query the existing transactions.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/testing/sandbox

Answer (score 1):

On The developer dashboard (https://developer.squareup.com/apps) you can see the  sandbox test accounts, there is an **open** button next to the account, click on it and it will open the sandbox dashboard, there you can see the sandbox transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You go to your Square Developer Dashboard. You should have a Default Test Account. Open it up and you can go to the Sandbox Dashboard and see all your transactions and associated data based on the use of the API

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is a way to view the sandbox transactions before you go live. Go to this link developer.squareup.com/apps and there at the bottom you can see the list of sandbox test accounts. Click open button to view the dashboard.